# Vue.js toggle specific items

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Vue.js beginner here :-)

I have some `testblock` divs which have `teststep` child divs. There is a `testblock` toggle button to toggle all `testblock` elements and every `testblock` has a toggle button to toggle its child `teststeps`:

```
<div id="app">
    <div><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" @click="showTestblock = !showTestblock">Toggle testblocks</button></div>
    <div v-if="showTestblock">Testblock-1</div>
        <div v-if="showTestblock"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" @click="showTeststep = !showTeststep">Toggle teststeps</button></div>
        <div v-if="showTeststep">Teststep-1a</div>
        <div v-if="showTeststep">Teststep-1b</div>
    <div v-if="showTestblock">Testblock2</div>
        <div v-if="showTestblock"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" @click="showTeststep = !showTeststep">Toggle teststeps</button></div>
        <div v-if="showTeststep">Teststep-2a</div>
        <div v-if="showTeststep">Teststep-2b</div>
    <div v-if="showTestblock">Testblock3</div>
        <div v-if="showTestblock"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" @click="showTeststep = !showTeststep">Toggle teststeps</button></div>
        <div v-if="showTeststep">Teststep-3a</div>
        <div v-if="showTeststep">Teststep-3b</div>
</div>
```

And the Vue code:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showTestblock: false,
    showTeststep: false
  }
})
```

There are 2 issues:

1. Toggle a `teststep` toggles all teststeps, not only the ones of the
   specific `testblock`. In JQuery I would add an ID, but has Vue a
   better way of doing this?
2. When `teststeps` are shown and the `testblock` toggle button is
   clicked, the testblocks are not shown anymore, but the `teststeps`
   are. How to close children also?

Update:

Updated code with proper nesting:

```
<div id="app">
    <div><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" @click="showTestblock = !showTestblock">Toggle testblocks</button>
        <div v-if="showTestblock"><span>Testblock-1</span>
            <div v-if="showTestblock"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" @click="showTeststep = !showTeststep">Toggle teststeps</button>
                <div v-if="showTeststep">Teststep-1a</div>
                <div v-if="showTeststep">Teststep-1b</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div v-if="showTestblock"><span>Testblock-2</span>
            <div v-if="showTestblock"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" @click="showTeststep = !showTeststep">Toggle teststeps</button>
                <div v-if="showTeststep">Teststep-2a</div>
                <div v-if="showTeststep">Teststep-2b</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div v-if="showTestblock"><span>Testblock-3</span>
            <div v-if="showTestblock"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" @click="showTeststep = !showTeststep">Toggle teststeps</button>
                <div v-if="showTeststep">Teststep-3a</div>
                <div v-if="showTeststep">Teststep-3b</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Toggle a teststep toggles all teststeps, not only the ones of the testblock." - no surprises here. Your test-steps are not folded into parent test-blocks. Try to change html structure and probably you will solve your second issue. About the first one - probably it's just better to use different flags for different blocks. It seems naturally I think. If you wan jQ-like approach - probably you also can add an id to element, write function for click handler and manually do something with dom node (but this way is against frameworks like vue, and it's better to avoid direct dom mutations).

Comment: yes, there's a better way. What you're doing is no different from using the exact same name for all the relative stuff and expecting something like `document.getElementsByName` to be able to distinguish exactly what you want. Why aren't you either using 1. an array 2. an object?

Comment: @Alendorff you're right, the nesting was terrible, so I updated that. Now issue 2 has been solved. What do you mean with: `probably it's just better to use different flags for different blocks`? Can you give a brief example?